# Trying to get array to print to console and assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hoping someone can help me out with this. I am working with a url that contains an array. Im not sure why I cant get this to print to the console. It shows in the debugger tab that it is working however. Im pretty sure it has do to with the fact that the data is not json, its just an array but i need to use JSONP or else i get the cors error.

```
    // Where to Buy State Selection Options

var stateData = {};

$(document).ready(function() {

  "use strict";

  $("#mapWhereToBuy").usmap({ 
    click: function(event, data) { 
       var description = '';
       switch(data.name){
          case 'AL': 
              description = 'Alabama';
              break;
          case 'AK':
              description = 'Alaska';
              break;
          case 'AZ':
              description = 'Arizona';
              break;
          case 'AR':
              description = 'Arkansas'; 
              break;
          case 'CA':
              description = 'California';
              break;
          case 'CO':
              description = 'Colorado';
              break;
          case 'CT':
              description = 'Connecticut';
              break;
          case 'DC': 
              description = 'District of Columbia';
              break;
          case 'DE':
              description = 'Delaware';
              break;
          case 'FL':
              description = 'Florida';
              break;
          case 'GA': 
              description = 'Georgia';
              break;
          case 'HI':
              description = 'Hawaii';
              break;    
          case 'ID':
              description = 'Idaho';
              break;    
          case 'IL':
              description = 'Illinois';
              break;    
          case 'IN':
              description = 'Indiana';
              break;    
          case 'IA':
              description = 'Iowa';
              break;
          case 'KS':
              description = 'Kansas';
              break;
          case 'KY':
              description = 'Kentucky';
              break;
          case 'LA':
              description = 'Louisiana';
              break;
          case 'ME':
              description = 'Maine';
              break;
          case 'MD':
              description = 'Maryland';
              break;
          case 'MA':
              description = 'Massachusetts';
              break;
          case 'MI':
              description = 'Michigan';
              break;
          case 'MN':
              description = 'Minnesota';
              break;
          case 'MS':
              description = 'Mississippi';
              break;
          case 'MO':
              description = 'Missouri';
              break;
          case 'MT':
              description = 'Montana';
              break;
          case 'NE':
              description = 'Nebraska';
              break;
          case 'NV':
              description = 'Nevada';
              break;
          case 'NH':
              description = 'New Hampshire';
              break;
          case 'NJ':
              description = 'New Jersey'; 
              break;
          case 'NM':
              description = 'New Mexico'; 
              break;
          case 'NY':
              description = 'New York';
              break;
          case 'NC':
              description = 'North Carolina';
              break;
          case 'ND':
              description = 'North Dakota';
              break;
          case 'OH':
              description = 'Ohio';
              break;
          case 'OK':
              description = 'Oklahoma';
              break;
          case 'OR':
              description = 'Oregon';
              break;
          case 'PA':
              description = 'Pennsylvania';
              break;
          case 'RI':
              description = 'Rhode Island';
              break;
          case 'SC':
              description = 'South Carolina';
              break;
          case 'SD':
              description = 'South Dakota';
              break;
          case 'TN':
              description = 'Tennessee';
              break;
          case 'TX':
              description = 'Texas';
              break;
          case 'UT':
              description = 'Utah';
              break;
          case 'VT':
              description = 'Vermont';
              break;
          case 'VA':
              description = 'Virginia';
              break;
          case 'WA':
              description = 'Washington';
              break;
          case 'WV': 
              description = 'West Virginia';
              break;
          case 'WI':
              description = 'Wisconsin';
              break;  
          case 'WY':
              description = 'Wyoming';
              break;  
       }  

       $('#clicked-state').text(description); 
       console.log('called ' + data.name); 
       $.ajax({     
            dataType: "jsonp",    
            url: 'https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxx/test/test/state/' + data.name,
            cache: true, 
            success: function(data){  
               stateData = JSON.stringify(data); 
               console.log(stateData);
            }
       });  

    } 
  });   

});
```

Comment: Can you include a runnable example so that we can help you further? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing your code working or at least an error message. There could be any number of reasons an AJAX request doesn't work. Given the demo though, I'd guess it's a JSONP/CORS issue. Also note that the mammoth `switch` statement can be simplified to an object key lookup to return the description.

Comment: If your console after `JSON.stringify` is fine, than it **is** a JSON, you have other problem. Please add the response data sample.

Comment: Aside: Instead of a huge switch statement you would be better off to use just a standard object full of key -> value pairs.

Comment: Where is the array you are talking about ? And which `console.log` is the one not printing the expected variable ?

Comment: the array is in that url, all im trying to do is assign is assign it to a variable called StateData and literally print it to the console

Comment: Did you check network tab what was come from server

Comment: yeah its coming in as a callback it says in the network tab. im just wondering how i can actually reference the data